# ui:repeat, populate list

Tags: jsf, arraylist

I have a similiar problem to this questions (old question)

[Inner UI:repeat does not bind to a bean in a nested UI:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943478/inner-uirepeat-does-not-bind-to-a-bean-in-a-nested-uirepeat)

My problem is I can't figure out how to populate values in that matrix. I have tried several ways with the list, but no way.

Thanks